# How to remove port number from Django application

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have deployed a Django application to virtual server using nginx as proxy server and Gunicorn. The application is binded like

```
gunicorn --bind example.com:8000 MyApp.wsgi:application
```

My nginx is configured like

```
server {
    server_name <my_ip_address>;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/examApp/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
```

Here the problem is, the application is working fine on www.example.com. But when we use Django password reset, the reset email contains link like this `http://example.com:8000/reset/MjA/466-434d4ewe54546878b4/`

How to remove that `port number 8000` from the link.

Comment: That would be an issue with the application, not the server.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Actually the link changes as I changes the binding address. Say If I am using `gunicorn --bind example.com:8005 MyApp.wsgi:application` the link shows `example.com:8005`

Comment: And it's *still* an application issue.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Can you throw some light for solving the issue? :)

Comment: Change how the application generates those links.

Comment: You really shouldn't be binding gunicorn to the domain at all. You should use a purely local address, eg 127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for letting me know the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try configuring [the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/).

[`PasswordResetForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordResetForm) uses [`domain`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#django.contrib.sites.models.Site.domain) by default which is stored in database and can be changed to whatever you need.